# Checking null String in android

Tags: java, android, string

I am developing an android application.I am getting a String value as null from webservice. I am fetching the value and storing it in a String variable. Then when I print the value using Log, like Log.i("tag", "````!!!cell >>"+cell);, I an getting null printed in the screen. Now what i need is that I need to check the variable for 'null' and I want to display a textfield with no value if it is 'null'. I am using the following statement for checking

```
if(!cell.equals(null) || !cell.equals("")) {
  _______
} else {
  _______
}
```

But the control is not going inside the else part if the value us 'null'

Please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have null String literal? then you need to try !cell.equals("null");

Answer (score 11):

when `cell`  is null , and you are trying to invoke a method on it, you will hit by a null pointer exception.

I'd say

```
if(cell !=null  &&  !cell.isEmpty()) {
  _______yes, disply
} else {
  _______nope, some thing wrong
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its not `equals(null)` its

```
if(cell != null || !cell.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 1):

I would give try this, seems to be working for me!

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString) && yourString == null){

}
else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString) && yourString != null){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the string is null, `!cell.equals("")` will evaluate to true and hence it will go in the if part and not the else part as you are using an OR condition.

NULL != "" (Empty string)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
if (cell != null && cell.trim().length() > 0) {
    // do whatever you want
} else {
    // the string received is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android provides a simple utility

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(<<stringVariable>>);
```

More details @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

WORKING !!!

```
 if (string.matches("")&& string.trim().equals("null")){

    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
```